# Send a request in soapUI impersonating someone other than oneself

Tags: ssl, http-headers, soapui, distinguishedname

I have a POST request step in soapUI that works successfully with my SSL certificate.

It uses the certificate (key may be more accurate) that I saved in soapUI's application configuration settings.

What I want to do is make this request as some test user Bob.  Bob has a DN in the system under test.

How to do this?

Adding a header to the request had no effect. I tried X-ProxiedEntitiesChain.

Do I need to remove the key from the settings in order for soapUI to use the header I supply?

Comment: Hi, do you need to change the user dynamically or just need to be able to send your request with different credentials during a distinct test run ?

Comment: The former would be ideal, but I will settle for the latter for now.

Comment: Do you use SOAP UI pro ?